# Cartoon movie about a boy student and a new girl student who is the princess of a secret toy world

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

There is cool guy in the toy world princess's class, who she planned to give the power to become the prince of her world, but unfortunately she mistakenly gave the powers to the protagonist. The protagonist chooses the hero he wants to become and they fight a villain in the toy world. It turns out the villain is the hero that the boy chose.

Comment: Hello Ammar Yasser, welcome to [fantasy.se]. Please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) to jog your memory. If you remember any additional clues, you can [edit] your question to add those. Most importantly, when and where did you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Doom Kitten's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/251287/23243) is essentially correct, if perhaps too terse. The 2005 animated film, *[The Toy Warrior](https://archive.org/details/the-toy-warror)*, involves Princess Sherbert (a character from Jinoo's favorite toyline, *The Toy Warrior*) meaning to recruit Jason, in Jinoo's class, who has impressive martial skills for his age, but Jinoo accidentally touches the stone, choosing to become The Toy Warrior. And indeed, the villain does turn out to be The Toy Warrior.

> The Land Of Toys is a world of pure imagination, ruled by the popular doll Princess Sherbet, but when the mysterious Dark One threatens Sherbet's toy kingdom, she turns to the real world in search of a heroic Warrior Prince... Unfortunately, she ends up with the imaginative trouble-maker Jinoo. When Jinoo accidentally touches Sherbet's magical Warrior Stone, the spunky sixth-grader is suddenly transported to the Land Of Toys to become the powerful Toy Warrior! Aided by the reluctant Princess Sherbet, the transforming Police-bot, R.J., and Jinoo's amazingly loyal backpack, Ping, Jinoo is ready to play Toy Warrior and chase the dark forces across the landscape of imagination. The evil is spreading and now both the real world and the very Well of Imagination itself are at stake! Our only hope is a hero with heart... the Toy Warrior Jinoo!

The Internet Archive entry I linked has the best description I can find, but the movie itself is chopped up. I have seen some suggestions that this was the pilot to an intended series that never got off the ground.

[image: The Toy Warrior throws off his costume of the Dark One]

Answer (score 0):

The Toy Warrior (2005)?

[The Toy Warrior IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0363141/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _The Toy Warrior_ matches the movie described in the question. Copying and pasting the IMDB synopsis into your answer would be helpful too. [This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/122024) offers guidance on how to write a good story ID answer. You might also wish to take the [tour], to learn more about the site in general.