# What is this king of birds movie name?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It's a movie about 2 brothers, a rich mean one and a poor humble one. The rich one had a cat apparently. The poor guy lived a poor humble life till one day a bird came to live out of his house.

A few days later the bird got attacked. The guy saved it and helped to heal it. Then the bird left, and next morning the guy saw a huge giant egg in front of his house.

The egg made him rich, as when he opened the egg, his brother tried to kidnap the bird.

His brother had a plan in which he brought a snake to the bird so he can act like he saved it, but the bird went and came back with 3 giant eggs each with a bad thing for the mean brother.

What's the movie or the cartoon

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: So, did the egg make him rich (how?), and then his brother tried to kidnap the bird? Or was his brother trying to kidnap the bird what made him rich?

Comment: By the by, when you return, can you verify whether https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/255084/23243 is correct?

Comment: :) If *The Toy Warrior* is correct, can you accept it by clicking on the checkmark over there?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The querent identified the film as the 2008 film *[The Queen of Swallows](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5334028/)*

[image: Front cover of The Queen of the Swallows]

It is an adaptation of the Korean folk tale, "[The King of the Birds](https://gaana.com/song/the-king-of-the-birds-3)" ([text version](https://www.storynory.com/the-king-of-the-birds/)), which follows a standard formula in many fairy tales where someone does a good deed to an animal, and is rewarded, and when someone else tries to selfishly follow the same template, they're punished for it.

In most versions of the story that I've found, the gifts (and punishments) are conveyed in seeds that grow into giant pumpkins, which have the items inside.

Here's [one of the short versions](https://wp.dinolingo.com/korean-for-kids/korean-culture/popular-korean-folktales-short-stories-for-kids-in-korea-with-video/):

> Once upon a time, there were two brothers, Nolbu and Heungbu. Nolbu was rich but greedy. Heungbu was poor but generous. One day, Heungbu found a sparrow with a broken leg. He helped the bird and took it to his house. The bird got better and flew away. Later the sparrow brought three gourd seeds to Heungbu. The gourd became so big. When Heungbo cut it open a lot go gold coins came out. Nolbu heard the story and he also wanted the gold coins. He found a sparrow and broke its leg. The poor bird ran away and later brought 3 gourd seeds. The seeds grew and Nolbu cut them open. Suddenly the devils came out and started beating Nolbu. Nolbu learned a lesson that he shouldn’t be greedy.

The trailer can be viewed [here](https://vimeo.com/110566698).